# find maximum possible min value of array

Tags: algorithm

There is an array containing **n** integers. In each step we are allowed to increment all the elements present in any subarray of size **w** by 1. The maximum number of such steps allowed is **m**. Any element of the array cannot be incremented more than **k** times. We are required to maximize the minimum possible element in the array after these operations.

For example we are given ***n=6, m=2, w=3, k=1***

And the array is ***2 2 2 2 1 1***.

then the answer is ***2***, as k=1( we can only increment each element once, hence considering a window of size 3 at the end of the array will give us the required answer. Also note that since m=2, the first 3 elements will be incremented in the next step.)

How do i approach this problem?

Edit: Constraints are

1 ≤ w ≤ n ≤ 10^5

1 ≤ k ≤ m ≤ 10^5

Elements in the array are in range 1 to 10^9.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: This is not homework, I had this question in a programming test which I attempted and I didn't know how to approach it. So I was asking for suggestions on how to begin.

Comment: what are the maximum values of n,m,w,k ?

Comment: I have mentioned the constraints now, do have a look.